# tx_news - configuration of tags and categories in realurl, if both link to the same page?

Tags: tags, typo3, categories, realurl, tx-news

I use TYPO3 7.6.23 with news 6.1.1 and realurl 2.3.1 and included the realurl_config.php from the official news-documentation.

```
...
'newsCategoryConfiguration' => array(
    array(
        'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[overwriteDemand][categories]',
        'lookUpTable' => array(
            'table' => 'sys_category',
            'id_field' => 'uid',
            'alias_field' => 'title',
            'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
            'useUniqueCache' => 1,
            'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
                'strtolower' => 1,
                'spaceCharacter' => '-'
            )
        )
    )
),
'newsTagConfiguration' => array(
    array(
        'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[overwriteDemand][tags]',
        'lookUpTable' => array(
            'table' => 'tx_news_domain_model_tag',
            'id_field' => 'uid',
            'alias_field' => 'title',
            'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
            'useUniqueCache' => 1,
            'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
                'strtolower' => 1,
                'spaceCharacter' => '-'
            )
        )
    )
),
'50' => 'newsDetailConfiguration',
'8' => 'newsTagConfiguration',                           
'8' => 'newsCategoryConfiguration',
...
```

Now I want to filter the news by category or by tags on a single list page (id=8). But I get only a nice "category"-url displayed, not a nice "tag"-url. The newsCategoryConfiguration overrides the newsTagConfiguration. How can I get a nice url for tags as well?

Answer (score 0):

Your realurl code is correct.

i think this is a cache problems. So clear all BE cache( in Install TOOL).

1) realurl cache paths:  RealUrl Page Module -> Root Page -> `Flush all entries (harmful!)`

2) Remove typo3temp file.enter code here

Comment: I tried these steps and also truncated all tables related to realurl, but the problem remains. The last entry ('8' => 'newsCategoryConfiguration') overrides the previous entry ( '8' => 'newsTagConfiguration').

Answer (score 0):

`'8' => 'newsTagConfiguration',

'8' => 'newsCategoryConfiguration',`

This will not work because the second `'8'` will overwrite the first one.